# How to creating ACOs?

Tags: cakephp, acl

I think I have undestood the bases of almost everything in `CakePHP` until the `Access Control Lists`, now I'm on [11.2.5 Creating ACOs (Access Control Objects)](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1548/Creating-ACOs-Access-Control-Objects) and I don't understand where I have to put the `AclComponent` methods:

```
   $this->Acl->Aco->create(array('parent_id' => null, 'alias' => 'controllers'));
   $this->Acl->Aco->save();
```

In which file I should insert this code?

Have I to inserti in some specific statement?
I don't undestand what this line does exactly, so I can't locate where and when it should run, what this code does, and when It should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea with the ACO records creation is that if your project is over (meaning no new actions are created), you don't need to insert anything anymore in the acos datatable. These methods are intended to be called once, or only a few times.

It is then up to you to decide where you want to place these lines of code, as anyway you will probably remove them afterwards.

Alternatively, to fill the acos datatable, you could also use this plugin http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl that automatically detects new actions and propose to complete the acos datatable accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can insert that wherever you need to create Aco-s. in app_controller, or in any controller.

Answer (score 0):

This page in the Cookbook gives you a very nice automated tool for creating ACOs:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/647/An-Automated-tool-for-creating-ACOs

If you add the build_acl function to the AppController, you can run it from any controller and it generates your ACOs for you.  It's always worked very nicely in my ACL-using applications.